# Catch error during Buffer creation with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch, buffer

Suppose I am creating a binary buffer using node.js with the code below;

```
msg_str = "0105A"; //this gives error. Correct version will be something like "0105AB"
buffer_binary = new Buffer(msg_str, "hex"); // specify hex
console.log(msg_str); 
console.log(buffer_binary);
```

This will give an error like this;

> buffer.js:568
>           return this.hexWrite(string, offset, length);
>                       ^
>
> TypeError: Invalid hex string
>       at TypeError (native)
>       at Buffer.write (buffer.js:568:21)
>       at fromString (buffer.js:115:26)
>       at new Buffer (buffer.js:54:12)

How could the code be modified to catch this error and not exit abruptly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could simply use a try/catch block given it's synchronous.

```
msg_str = "0105A"; //this gives error. Correct version will be something like "0105AB"
try {
  buffer_binary = new Buffer(msg_str, "hex"); // specify hex
} 
catch (err){
  // return, callback or whatever else you want to happen
}    
console.log(msg_str); 
console.log(buffer_binary);
```